# My computer stops responding when I unlock it after a Remote Desktop connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, freeze, login, login-screen

I use Remote Desktop a lot to connect to my PC. But lately I've run into a problem with it. When I connect, it works fine, but then when I go to unlock my computer locally, it usually just hangs on a black screen and I need to reboot. The computer doesn't freeze entirely, as I can still use the mouse, and connect to it over the network.

One thing I've noticed is that when it's in this "frozen" state, attempting to stop Remote Desktop Services (by typing `net stop "Remote Desktop Services"` over an SSH connection) it tells me it's attempting to stop the service, but I waited a while and nothing happened.

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong. The NVIDIA GeForce Experience software was causing the problem. I read somewhere that its "share" feature, whatever that is, can cause this problem. I didn't see any way to disable that feature, but I never used the software anyway, so I just uninstalled it. This fixed the problem.